# Title search is not working

Tags: custom-fields, search, title

I have the following search functionality for the channel entries and Iam searching based on their titles like

```
{exp:channel:entries loose_search='no' orderby='bump_up_date' sort="desc" 
<?php if(isset($GLOBALS["search"])) { ?> search:title="<?php echo $GLOBALS["search"];?>" <?php } ?>  }

{/exp:channel_entries}
```

But it is not returning desired result.If i place title with anyother field like description it is working fine.Can anyone tell me the solution please.Thanks in regards.

Comment: I have seem same question and answer here http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/753/searchtitle-doesnt-work and hope it would help you.

Comment: yes I have that plugin also but not working

Comment: can you share your code with that plugin. Also what is "PHP Parsing Stage" for this template.

Comment: Actually while printing the query for the title the search query is empty...I think we need to add it in custome field...Where can I add it..??